# Get amount of open fibers in ruby

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, fiber, em-synchrony

How can I get the current amount of open Fibers in a `ruby` application? My app uses EventMachine Synchrony lib for concurrency handling. While googling, I've not found any API which would return it.

For example if I have this piece of code:

```
EM::Synchrony::FiberIterator.new(@outputs, @outputs.size).each do |output|
# some code goes here
end
```

then how can I know how many fibers are there running? Without manually using `counter++` and of course without `@some_arr.size`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so 1 solution was found for this issue:

You can count number of existing objects (of all types) in ruby.

In our case we want to count the objects of type/class **'Fiber'**, so we use `ObjectSpace.each_object` ruby API:

```
stats = {}
stats["Fiber"] = 0
ObjectSpace.each_object(Fiber) {|o| stats["Fiber"] += 1 if o.alive?}
```

(we are interested only in alive Fibers, that's why using `alive?` API)

ObjectSpace for reference:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html

Fiber for reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html